# Custom component does not accept styles react material ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-css-modules

I have an `Avatar Component` that I have created, its a very basic component that displays an icon and some text. This is the code for the component.

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withStyles, Avatar, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import avatar_placeholder from "../images/avatar_man.svg";

const styles = theme => ({
  row: {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  avatar: {
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    marginRight: "2%"
  },
  subtitle: {
    opacity: 0.5
  }
});

const customAvatar = props => {
  const { classes, name, subtitle } = props;

  return (
    <div className={classes.row}>
      <Avatar alt={name} src={avatar_placeholder} />
      <div>
        <Typography variant="title">{name}</Typography>
        <Typography variant="body2" className={classes.subtitle}>
          {subtitle}
        </Typography>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

customAvatar.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  image: PropTypes.string,
  subtitle: PropTypes.string
};

customAvatar.defaultProps = {
  name: "John Doe",
  subtitle: ""
};

export default withStyles(styles)(customAvatar);
```

The `Avatar` component is the child component of a parent, the code that follows is how the `Avatar` component is used in the parent.

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import {
  withStyles,
  Card,
  CardContent
} from "@material-ui/core";
import AvatarProfile from "./AvatarProfile";

const styles = {
  cardContent: {
  },
  AvatarDiv: {
    backgroundColor: "red"
  }
};

const ItemCardWithCheckbox = props => {
  const { classes, name, subtitle } = props;

  return (
    <Card>
      <CardContent className={classes.cardContent}>
        <AvatarProfile
          name={name}
          subtitle={subtitle}
          className={classes.AvatarDiv}
        />
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
  );
};

ItemCardWithCheckbox.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default withStyles(styles)(ItemCardWithCheckbox);
```

As you can see I am trying to apply the `AvatarDiv` style for the `Avatar` component ie, I would like the `backgroundColor` of the `Avatar` component to be red but that's not happening, I am using [Material UI](https://material-ui.com/). My guess is either the style props aren't being passed properly to the `Avatar` component or I'm not applying the style correctly.

Comment: From where `classes.AvatarDiv` coming? I see it is an property of `styles` object..

Comment: share your `AvatarProfile' component.

Comment: @SakhiMansoor the `customAvatar ` component is the `AvatarProfile`

Comment: @ArupRakshit that's pretty much it, they style object is what is used to style everything in that component, I have skipped out the styles for `classes.cardContent` for brevity but all styles written inside `cardContent` are being applied correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing AvatarDiv as 'className' prop. You are not applying the class here, as AvatarDiv is a custom component.

```
  <AvatarProfile
          name={name}
          subtitle={subtitle}
          className={classes.AvatarDiv}
```

You have to pass it as props and use that prop to apply the style in the child component. I have done something similar in the codesandbox, where i change the color to orange for the button and pass it as prop to child component . Please check - https://codesandbox.io/s/lyxz92m7nl

Answer (score 1):

I have made it more readable and smart component and use a single stlyles component. 
Here is the working codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/ll507vypy7